# Check if Element is iFrame or Object (PHP-Xpath)

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I wrote a script that uses PHP DOM. I'm parsing a webpage and accessing the elements through XPath.

Everything works fine except when it comes to getting a Node that will have either an  tag or an  tag.

What I want to do is basically:

if element tag is 'object' then 
< execute code here >

elseif element tag is 'iFrame' then
< excecute alternative code>

Some Div Blocks will have:
Code:

```
<div class="scenario1" > 
<object src=xxxx... />
```

While others will have:

Code:

```
<div class="scenario2" > 
<iFrame src=xxxx... />
```

This is the the only part left that's messing me up now. Any idea how do differentiate between an element type?It always displays a blank line if its an IFrame (I have an Xpath leading to the parent node that check for the object tag). I've tried checking if the node is empty/null then trying to search for a iFrame but it wasn't working for me and returned a blank line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tagName` property, for example if `$elem` is a DOMElement:

```
if(strtolower($elem->tagName) == 'iframe'))
{
    // it's an iframe
}
```